# Simplifying $\cos(2\arctan(y/x))$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry

Hi I am looking for a way to calculate/simplify the following
$$
e^{2i \phi}= \cos(2\phi)+i\sin(2\phi).
$$
where $\phi=\arctan(y/x)$. I want to simplify so it is an expression with no trig functions.  As done for the more simple case,
$$
e^{i\phi}=\cos \phi+i\sin \phi 
$$
So I get
$$
\cos \phi =\cos(\arctan(y/x))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\quad \sin \phi = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$
Thus I can simplify $e^{i\phi}$ easily, but
How can I calculate $\cos (2\phi), \sin(2\phi)$ ? (without using wolfram alpha)
$$
\cos(2\phi)=\cos(2\arctan(y/x))=?,\quad \sin(2\phi)=\sin(2\arctan(y/x))=?
$$ I get stuck here.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956782/what-is-cos2-tan-1x2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$
\cos 2\phi = 2\cos^2 \phi - 1 = \frac{2x^2}{x^2 + y^2} - 1 = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2+y^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

cos(2tan$^{-1}$($\frac{y}{x}$)).

We if Z = tan$^{-1}$($\frac{y}{x}$) then, tan(Z) = $\frac{y}{x}$. What you want is  cos(2tan$^{-1}$($\frac{y}{x}$)) = cos(2Z) = $\frac{1-tan^{2}Z}{1+tan^{2}Z}$ and you already have tan(Z).